# Swift3: Add button with code

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

Im reading Apples swift (iOS) documentation but its written for Swift 2 and i use Swift 3. I want to add a button programmatically but its seems there is a change and I can't find how to fix it.

Here is the Code for the Swift 2 example:

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {

// MARK: Initialization

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Buttons
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    addSubview(button)
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}

// MARK: Button Action

func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton){
    print("Button pressed")
}
}
```

The only change i made after the 'fix-it' showed the error is this in the selector:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchDown)
```

This should have printed "Button pressed" but it doesn't. Any help?

Comment: What about your RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:) method? It depends on the implementation of it.

Comment: I don't know if thats a problem since everything I wrote is from Apples example... here is the link : tinyurl.com/q5oouqz

Comment: @OnurTuna the selector only references it, it should not depend on the implementation

Comment: @Gerald I mean if there is an error depended on the arguments for example.

Answer (score 20):

My code:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)

override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
//override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    //...
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}

// MARK: Button Action
func ratingButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed ")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer in terms of the problem in the docs when using Swift 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this. I haven't tested but it should work:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
addSubview(button)

func ratingButtonTapped() {
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. For some reason the:

```
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton)
```

needs an "_" before button. So it should be :

```
func ratingButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton)
```

And the other part of the code must be :

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Thanks for helping :) Your method may be correct also but thats the one Apple wants it.

Comment: In swift 3, all parameters are named, even the first parameter, unlike in swift 2. a better solution is `#selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:))`. this way you do not have to change your function just to use it in the selector